# pdf flutter // image attach does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I tried so many ways... I have no clue how to attach an Image from the assets folder in the pdf...

If I add this in line 30:

```
pw.MemoryImage(
(await rootBundle.load('assets/img/your_image.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List(),
);
```

The programm crashes...

The pdf should contain an image of the logo. It is an web application, so when the user clicked on the button it should Download the pdf. That is working. But I am not able to add Images...

Main Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PDFSave extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PDFSaveState createState() => _PDFSaveState();
}

class _PDFSaveState extends State<PDFSave> {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  var anchor;

  savePDF() async {
    Uint8List pdfInBytes = await pdf.save();
    final blob = html.Blob([pdfInBytes], 'application/pdf');
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
      ..href = url
      ..style.display = 'none'
      ..download = 'pdf.pdf';
    html.document.body?.children.add(anchor);
  }

  createPDF() async {
    
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Column(
          children: [
            pw.Column(
              children: [
                pw.Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    pw.Text('Rechnung', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
                    pw.Container(
                      padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration:
                          pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(width: 2)),
                      child: pw.BarcodeWidget(
                        color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
                        barcode: pw.Barcode.qrCode(),
                        data: "My data",
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                pw.Divider(
                  height: 2,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    savePDF();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createPDF();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PDF Creator'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Press'),
          onPressed: () {
            anchor.click();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried attaching many code snipped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer is quite simple.

First, check that the assets ordner is in the pubspec

Use this code to add a image to a PDF and download it in a web browser.

If there is an error, JUST RESTART YOUR IDE!!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PDFSave extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PDFSaveState createState() => _PDFSaveState();
}

class _PDFSaveState extends State<PDFSave> {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  var anchor;

  savePDF() async {
    Uint8List pdfInBytes = await pdf.save();
    final blob = html.Blob([pdfInBytes], 'application/pdf');
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
      ..href = url
      ..style.display = 'none'
      ..download = 'pdf.pdf';
    html.document.body?.children.add(anchor);
  }

  createPDF() async {
    final ByteData image = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.PNG');
    Uint8List imageData = (image).buffer.asUint8List();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Column(
          children: [
            pw.Column(
              children: [
                pw.Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    pw.Text('Rechnung', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
                    pw.Container(
                      padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration:
                          pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(width: 2)),
                      child: pw.BarcodeWidget(
                        color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
                        barcode: pw.Barcode.qrCode(),
                        data: "My data",
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                pw.Divider(
                  height: 2,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
                pw.Container(
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: pw.Image(
                    pw.MemoryImage(imageData),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    savePDF();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createPDF();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PDF Creator'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Press'),
          onPressed: () {
            anchor.click();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Finished pdf with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAHtL.png)